# how to rewrite a script using sed of variable with zenity folder select content

Tags: linux, bash, sh

i have:

```
dir="null"

if [ $dir = "null" ] || [ $$dir = "" ] || [ $dir = "1" ] || [ $dir = "0" ]; then
zenity --info --tittle="Launcher Config" --text="locate your server folder"
way="$(zenity --file-selection --directory)"
zenity --info --text="$way"
sed -i 's/^dir=.*/dir="'$way'"/' ls.sh
```

but the terminal returns:

```
sed: -e expression #1, character 16: unknown option for the command 's' (s///?)
```

i dont know what it means U.U

Comment: Isn't `$Sway` just a typo? You're using `way` everywhere else...

Comment: @RolandSmith It might be a typo but it can not be the reason for the error message. The error messages says, that there must be a character after the third `/`, which `sed` does not understand. And because there is no character after the terminating `/`, there must be another `/` in the replacement string, which is followed by some character not known by `sed`.

Comment: You should double-quote all variable references; for example `[ $dir = "null" ]` will get an error if `$dir` is blank, or contains any whitespace or wildcards. Also, in `[ $$dir = "" ]` I think you have a doubled `$` (in the shell, `$$` expands to the PID of the shell process).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that `$way` contains a `/`. You have to quote all characters with a special meaning in a `sed` expression, if you build the `sed` program by concatenation of strings.

Try

```
sed -i "s/^dir=.*/dir=${way//\//\\/}/" ls.sh
```

Comment: now returns:
sed: -e expression #1, character 18: unknown option for the command 's' (s///?)

before was: character 16

Comment: I researched these bars and realized that in your script it contains 2 bars at the end and it was only one: 
sed -i "s/^dir=.*/dir=${way//\//\\//}/" ls.sh | sed -i "s/^dir=.*/dir=${way//\//\\/}/" ls.sh

Comment: @oblinez have fixed it